# How to access machines ? route table configured with same private ip to the different network interfaces

Tags: networking, network-programming, virtualbox

I need to start machines of same private ip (different vpn) with different interfaces connected. I changed my routing table as follows:

```
**Destination    Gateway           Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface**


192.168.79.0       *                255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vboxnet1

192.168.79.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vboxtap0

192.168.79.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vboxnet2

192.168.79.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vboxnet3
```

Now if i start two virtual machines with same ip(192.168.79.1) with diffent interfaces vboxnet1, vboxnet0
from my host i can able to ping only vboxnet1 machine.

Is there any way to connect the machine using both interface and ip? so that the communication will happen through interface.

Answer (score 2):

Simulating a network with 2 devices, having the same IP is the same as doing it with hardware = IP conflict. They do have different MAC-addresses but they are fighting in the LAN for the same IP. I recommend using a different IP. If you however still want to use the same IP as a kind of failsafe, try setting up VRRP on both of the (virtual) devices:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Router_Redundancy_Protocol

Comment: we are creating the interfaces in the host machine for virtual machines. these are virtual network interfaces.

Comment: That is correct, however the behavior of the path selection is the same as in hardware setup. This means: when you have 2 virtual interfaces with the same address, they will have the same result as 2 hardware interfaces with the same address: ip conflict (2 MAC's fighting for the same IP in the ARP table). If you look at the MAC address of the 2 virtual interfaces, you will see that they both have a different MAC (generated by the virtualisation)

Comment: To illustrate, you can use "traceroute" to see the current path followed. (this path should go via your NEC to your virtual interface)

Comment: this is the output of traceroute command 
traceroute 192.168.79.1
traceroute to 192.168.79.1 (192.168.79.1), 30 hops max, 40 byte packets using UDP
 1  192.168.79.1 (192.168.79.1)  3.091 ms   2.010 ms   0.918 ms

Comment: is there any command like    ping 192.168.79.1%<interface_name>  this command is working for ipv6

Comment: You could setup a specific route via an interface (windows):

route add (destination subnet) mask(destination mask) (gateway) IF (interface)